# print the appengine model entity id in the html template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

Following is the simple database model i have:

```
class Notes(db.Model):
  text = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now in the url handler, i send all the notes to the template as follows:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    notes = Notes.all()
    self.render_template("index.html", {'notes':notes})
```

In the template i am using [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) templating engine, i want the `id` of each of the notes to be printed, so that i can embed an edit link, somewhat like this:

```
{% for note in notes %}
<p>  
 {{ note.text }} <br>
 {{ note.date }} <br>
 (<a href ="edit/{{note.key.id}}">edit </a>)
{% endfor %}
```

But the trouble is, i dont see anything printed, in place of `note.key.id`
As per the docs over [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key_id) `key` class represents a unique key for a database entity and this has a method `id`, its a numeric value. for a single note from the collection of notes i want the `id` of the note.

If i use the django templating engine i get the values `{{ notes.key.id }}` printed, but with `jinja2` i dont see it.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well replace the `href` line with the following:

```
(<a href ="edit/{{note.key().id()}}">edit </a>)
```

This shall be enough.

Comment: I just tested it, in my case I had to adapt your solution as follows: `{{ job.key.id() }}` (**key**, not *key()*), using python 2.7, flask, jinjia2, ndb...